# Django CSRF Protection with user-based get request

Tags: django, get, csrf, middleware

I have the following "profile" view in my django app:

```html
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    current_user = request.user
    student_profile = get_object_or_404(Student, student_user = current_user)
    reviews = StudentReview.objects.filter(target_student = student_profile).reverse()

    for stu_review in reviews:
        stu_review.review_seen = True
        stu_review.save()

    context = {
        'user': current_user,
        'profile': student_profile,
        'reviews': reviews,
        'is_logged_in': request.user.is_authenticated,
    }
    return render(request, 'polls/profile.html', context)
```

I was wondering whether or not this code is vulnerable to a CSRF attack. Since profile information is sensitive, and since profile information is displayed based on a user's identity, I wasn't sure whether someone could attempt a CSRF attack to display another user's profile information, or whether Django's middleware would take care of that. I have a number of views that behave similarly, so I want to make sure that this information is not at risk.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115794/should-i-use-csrf-protection-for-get-requests

Answer (score 0):

GET requests are not protected by Django's CSRF middleware. A CSRF attack is a possibility, but it would not disclose any information.

The way a CSRF attack works is that an attacker tricks a user (the victim) into visiting a specific page. Since the page is visited by the victim, any action on the page may be authorised using the victim's login session, rather than the attacker's login session. But, since the victim visits the page, the response is also send to the victim. The attacker has no way of reading the response (unless other vulnerabilities allow that, e.g. XSS).

In this specific example, a CSRF attack would only be able to mark reviews targeted at the victim as seen, without the victim actually seeing them. You need to decide whether that is harmless or an actual problem.